# falla en el estado de ElasticSearch en Debian 10

Tags: debian, elasticsearch, java-11, variables-de-configuración

Buen día a todos, en mi ultimo trabajo necesito ELK, inicie instalando Elasticsearch pero este error me sale cada vez que intento ver el estado de Elasticsearch y no me deja iniciar dicho programa:

```
● elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2021-05-21 16:42:15 -05; 24s ago
     Docs: https://www.elastic.co
  Process: 32138 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/systemd-entrypoint -p ${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid --quiet (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 32138 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 21 16:42:14 raspberry systemd-entrypoint[32138]:         at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:170)
May 21 16:42:14 raspberry systemd-entrypoint[32138]:         at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:161)
May 21 16:42:14 raspberry systemd-entrypoint[32138]:         at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86)
May 21 16:42:14 raspberry systemd-entrypoint[32138]:         at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:127)
May 21 16:42:14 raspberry systemd-entrypoint[32138]:         at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90)
May 21 16:42:14 raspberry systemd-entrypoint[32138]:         at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:126)
May 21 16:42:14 raspberry systemd-entrypoint[32138]:         at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:92)
May 21 16:42:15 raspberry systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 21 16:42:15 raspberry systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 21 16:42:15 raspberry systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
```

la versión del **SO** es

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
Codename:   buster
```

la versión de **java** es

```
openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-post-Debian-1deb10u1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-post-Debian-1deb10u1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

en el archivo **/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml** solo se configuro esto

```
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
cluster.name: my-application
#
```

en el archivo **/etc/default/elasticsearch** solo se configuro esto

```
################################
# Elasticsearch
################################

# Elasticsearch home directory
#ES_HOME=/usr/share/elasticsearch

# Elasticsearch Java path
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-i386/

# Elasticsearch configuration directory
# Note: this setting will be shared with command-line tools
ES_PATH_CONF=/etc/elasticsearch

# Elasticsearch PID directory
#PID_DIR=/var/run/elasticsearch
.
.
.
START_DAEMON=true
ES_USER=elasticsearch
ES_GROUP=elasticsearch
```

configure la ruta de **ES_JAVA_HOME** de esa forma, debido a que el directorio de Java esta ubicado en

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-i386/bin/java
```

soy nueva con este programa no se qué otra info se podría necesitar para tener una ayudita, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Para no lidiar con este y otros problemas que van a surgir instalando ELK, yo te recomiendo usar Docker, va a ser mucho mas rápido aprender a usar mas o menos Docker, que investigar y solucionar cada error, al menos en mi caso fue asi. En [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/search?q=&type=image) hay contenedores de todo separado o todo junto. Siempre es conveniente usar imágenes oficiales, pero **a modo de ejemplo** [esta](https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/sebp/elk) imágen tiene todo ELK junto y solo tienes que hacer

```
docker pull sebp/elk
```

y luego

```
sudo docker run -p 5601:5601 -p 9200:9200 -p 9600:9600 -it --name elk sebp/elk
```

Cuando termina todo tienes:

- Kibana en localhost:5601
- Elasticsearch en localhost:9200
- Logstash en localhost:9600